# I've got exception in agora when trying to parse remote user (host from web app) in flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, web, agora.io

I am using agora_rtc_engine on Flutter to create video call between mobile app and web app. But when I create call and try to connect to it from both applications, I get exception in mobile app:

```
    [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter (17642): #0      _$UserInfoFromJson (package:agora_rtc_engine/src/classes.g.dart:11:27)
E/flutter (17642): #1      new UserInfo.fromJson (package:agora_rtc_engine/src/classes.dart:39:7)
E/flutter (17642): #2      RtcEngine.getUserInfoByUid.<anonymous closure> (package:agora_rtc_engine/src/rtc_engine.dart:314:23)
E/flutter (17642): #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter (17642): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (17642): <asynchronous suspension>
```

It happens when I try call method `getUserInfoByUid` in callback `userJoined ().`

Here is my code:

```
Engine initialising.

Future _initEngine() async {
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(widget.appId ?? APP_ID);
    _addListeners();
    final userAccount = '${widget.residentId}|${widget.residentName}|1';
    _engine.registerLocalUserAccount(widget.appId ?? APP_ID, userAccount);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.disableAudio();
    await _engine.startPreview();
    await _engine.enableAudioVolumeIndication(300, 3, true);
    _engine.enableFaceDetection(true);
    if (widget.isBroadcast!) {
      await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
      await _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
    } else {
      await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.Communication);
      _engine.setParameters('{"che.audio.live_for_comm": true}');

    final VideoEncoderConfiguration configuration = VideoEncoderConfiguration();
    configuration.degradationPrefer = DegradationPreference.MaintainBalanced;
    _engine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(configuration);
    _engine.setParameters('{"rtc.sync_user_account_callback": true}');

    _joinChannel();
  }
```

Channel joining:

```
Future _joinChannel() async {
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    final userAccount = '${widget.residentId}|${widget.residentName}|1';

    await _engine.joinChannel(null, widget.channelName!, userAccount, 0);
  }
```

Here is callbacks overriding:

```
void _addListeners() {
    _engine
        .setRemoteSubscribeFallbackOption(StreamFallbackOptions.VideoStreamLow);
    _engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (channel, uid, elapsed) {
          currentConnectedUser = ConnectedUser(
            id: uid,
            name: widget.residentName,
            imageUrl: residentAvatarUrl,
            reshubId: widget.residentId,
            muteAudio: isAudioMuted,
            muteVideo: isVideoMuted,
          );

          setState(() {
            isJoined = true;
          });
        },
        error: (error) {
          print('agora error: ${error.toString()}');
        },
        userJoined: (uid, elapsed) async {
          final UserInfo account = await _engine.getUserInfoByUid(uid);
          late ConnectedUser user;

          if (account.userAccount.isEmpty) {
            user = ConnectedUser(
              id: uid,
              name: uid.toString(),
              reshubId: uid.toString(),
              muteAudio: false,
              muteVideo: false,
            );
          } else {
            final List<String> accSplit = account.userAccount.split('|');
            user = ConnectedUser(
              id: uid,
              reshubId: accSplit[0],
              name: accSplit[1],
              muteAudio: false,
              muteVideo: false,
              imageUrl: avatars[accSplit[0]],
            );
          }

          setState(() {
            connectedUsers.removeWhere((element) => element.id == user.id);
            connectedUsers.add(user);
          });
        },
        userInfoUpdated: (int num, UserInfo user) async {
          final List<String> accSplit = user.userAccount.split('|');
          final ConnectedUser usr = ConnectedUser(
              id: user.uid,
              reshubId: accSplit[0],
              name: accSplit[1],
              muteAudio: false,
              muteVideo: false,
              imageUrl: avatars[accSplit[0]]);

          setState(() {
            connectedUsers.removeWhere((element) => element.id == usr.id);
            connectedUsers.add(usr);
          });
        },
        remoteAudioStateChanged: (int uid, AudioRemoteState state,
            AudioRemoteStateReason reason, int elapsed) {
          if (reason == AudioRemoteStateReason.RemoteMuted) {
            setState(() {
              connectedUsers.forEach((element) {
                if (element.id == uid) {
                  element.muteAudio = true;
                  element.isSpeaking = false;
                }
              });
            });
          } else if (reason == AudioRemoteStateReason.RemoteUnmuted) {
            setState(() {
              connectedUsers.forEach((element) {
                if (element.id == uid) {
                  element.muteAudio = false;
                }
              });
            });
          }
        },
        remoteVideoStateChanged: (int uid, VideoRemoteState state,
            VideoRemoteStateReason reason, int elapsed) {
          if (reason == VideoRemoteStateReason.RemoteUnmuted) {
            setState(() {
              connectedUsers.forEach((element) {
                if (element.id == uid) {
                  element.muteVideo = false;
                }
              });
            });
          }
          if (reason == VideoRemoteStateReason.RemoteMuted) {
            setState(() {
              connectedUsers.forEach((element) {
                if (element.id == uid) {
                  element.muteVideo = true;
                }
              });
            });
          }
        },
        audioVolumeIndication: (listParticipants, totalVolume) {
          listParticipants.forEach((participant) {
            if (participant.volume > 4) {
              if (participant.uid == 0) {
                currentConnectedUser.isSpeaking = true;
              } else {
                connectedUsers
                    .firstWhereOrNull(
                        (element) => element.id == participant.uid)
                    ?.isSpeaking = true;
              }
            } else {
              if (participant.uid == 0) {
                currentConnectedUser.isSpeaking = false;
              } else {
                connectedUsers
                    .firstWhereOrNull(
                        (element) => element.id == participant.uid)
                    ?.isSpeaking = false;
              }
            }
          });
          setState(() {});
        },
        userOffline: (uid, reason) {
          setState(() {
            connectedUsers.removeWhere((element) => element.id == uid);
          });
        },
        leaveChannel: (stats) {
          setState(() {
            isJoined = false;
            connectedUsers.clear();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

All this code works fine if I connect between the same platforms, f.e. web + web or mobile + mobile. I have problems only when I try create connection between two different platforms.
Perhaps somebody has a manual about multiplatform settings? Or some ideas about how to set up agora for calling between two different platforms?

Comment: Attach your code attempt. Here's the documentation you asked for.
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/flutter/index.html

Comment: Share you code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get UserInfo by Uid for user, who is connected via Web-app. In agora for web-app you can only operate with uid (no any additional information). So, if you need to get data about connected user, try it the other way.